# How do I draw a line under only certain columns in a table?

Tags: tables, rules

I need it to look exactly like this:

[image]

How far I have come:

[image]

The thing that is missing is that a small line with "World Record", I need it to be like the picture above. Have to idea how to move the line to the other side.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage [Symbol]{upgreek}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llrc}

\hline
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thin] (1,0.5) -- (3,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\\\

\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Country} & \textbf{Event} & \textbf{Result}\\\hline
Anna-Karin Kammerling & Sweden & 50 m butterfly & 25.57\\ Wilson Kipketer & Denmark & 800 m & 2:11.96\\Jan Zelezný & Czech Republic & javelin throw & 98.5\\Sergei Bubka & Ukrain & pole vault & pole vault  \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper] {article}

\usepackage{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llrc}

\hline
&&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{World Record}}\\
\cline{3-4}
\\
\cline{1--1}
\\
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Country} & \textbf{Event} & \textbf{Result}\\\hline
Anna-Karin Kammerling & Sweden & 50 m butterfly & 25.57\\ Wilson Kipketer & Denmark & 800 m & 2:11.96\\Jan Zelezný & Czech Republic & javelin throw & 98.5\\Sergei Bubka & Ukrain & pole vault & pole vault  \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tanks allot for help :) but would you mind explaining the steps that you did so I can get a better understanding of what is happening in the code, with the commands.

Comment: `\cline` puts a line in the indicated columns.  You're making a tabular with four columns, I put a line in the last two.  The `\multicolumn` commands makes content span multiple columns, in this case two, with in this case its contents centered.

Answer (score 1):

The original table was generated using [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l l l r@{.}l }
  \toprule
  & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{World Record}} \\
  \cmidrule{3-5}
  \textbf{Name}         & \textbf{Country} & \textbf{Event} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Result}} \\
  \midrule
  Anna-Karin Kammerling & Sweden         & 50 m butterfly &   25&57 \\
  Wilson Kipketer       & Denmark        &          800 m & 2:11&96 \\
  Jan Zelezný           & Czech Republic &  javelin throw &   98&5  \\
  Sergei Bubka          & Ukrain         &     pole vault &    6&14 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The final column containing the **Result** is actually two columns, inserting a `.` as a column separator to ensure alignment around the "decimal." The same should be possible using `S`-column (from [`siunitx`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)).

---

Some more code explanations:

- The `tabular` is set to contain 5 columns with a column specification given by `l l l r@{.}l`.

  `l` denotes a column that is `l`eft-aligned, while `r` signifies a `r`-ight-aligned column. `@{<stuff>}` replaces the regular column separation with `<stuff>`. So, in this case, `r@{.}l` denotes a `r`ight-aligned column, followed by a `l`eft-aligned column with a `.` between them. This is used to align the **Result** column around the decimal point `.`.
- **World Record** should span over 3 columns, including the **Event** column, and the now double-column **Result** (`r@{.}l`). So, we skip the first two columns via `& &` and then introduce a `\multicolumn{3}{c}\textbf{World Record}}` to ensure the title across these `3` columns are `c`entred.
- `\cmidrule{<from>-<to>}` sets a rule that spans from `c`olumn `<from>` to `<to>`. Since we want this over **Event** and the double-column **Result**, we need it from `3` (which is for **Event**) to `5` (the `l`eft-aligned/last column associated with **Result**).
- Each element under **Result** is set using `<LHS>&<RHS>` in order to adhere to the `r@{.}l` style in the column specification. The `<LHS>` is set `r`ight-aligned, while `&` inserts `.` and `<RHS>` is set `l`eft-aligned. The end result is a visually-aligned decimal.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: @peachblossom, if you liked answer, than you can vote it (by clicking on up-triangle at top left side of answer) :-)

Comment: @peachblossom: Also see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)

Comment: Voted on your comments, thanks for great help :)

Comment: Tanks allot for help again :) but would you mind explaining the steps that you did so I can get a better understanding of what is happening in the code, with the commands.

Comment: @peachblossom: I've added some more detail at the end of the answer. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Thanks now it's more clear what is happening in the code :)